# AngleSharp не удается получить данные сайта

Tags: c#, anglesharp

Простейший пример, взят с сайта библиотеки.

```
class MainClass
{
    static async void Test()
    {
        try
        {
            var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
            var address = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Big_Bang_Theory_episodes";
            var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
            var document = await context.OpenAsync(address);
            Console.WriteLine(document.Title);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test();
    }
}
```

На строке:

```
var document = await context.OpenAsync(address);
```

Происходит вылет из метода. Это не исключение, блоком try catch не отлавливается.
В логе следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Раньше такого не было. Версия библиотеки последняя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так это асинхронное программирование.

Когда выполнение доходит до `await` происходит возвращение из метода, что бы выполнить какую-либо полезную работу дальше, пока IO выполняется.

Тут я вижу следующие проблемы:

1. Вы возвращаете `void` => вы не можете дождаться снаружи выполнения данного метода
2. Вы не ждете конца в `Main`(да и не можете по первой причине)

Решения:
Либо делайте его полностью синхронным и вызывайте простой метод Open, который блокирует поток, либо доводите дело до конца исправя ошибки.